# Need help Android and iOS-App developed on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

Need some help on xamarin Platform. I understand it can be used to develop Android-base and iOS-base App on Xamarin. I have the following questions:

1. For Android and iOS-based app develop on Xamarin, can the app run on Android-tablet ad iOS-tablet respectively? what I need to do for both tablets respectively?
2. If there are new controls for android and iOS, how Xamarin will update this for development?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes they can run on Android Tablet and iPad. Your code logic would remain the same but you would need to provide for the UI since the resolutions are different.
For iOS, Xamarin makes it simple by providing for a Universal template which allows you to provide different layouts for iPhone & iPad.
For Android, there is no template as such but the process remains the same just as you would for phones with different resolutions.

2) Assuming you are talking about the default controls, they will made available in the Xamarin framework via their regular update channels. First they are in Alpha, then in Beta and once the bugs have been ironed out, they are made available to Stable channel which can then be used in the production apps safely.

I would recommend you go through their docs which are quite good and explains this whole thing in quite detail. [Xamarin Docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/)

Comment: Thank u so much. I have not been doing this so I may get a bit excited. Would appreciate if u can provide a link or reference showing how this is done. When u say change the UI resolution, which UI ? the Activity ? what size to change to? Appreciate yr help. for(2), u means the Xamarin will update itself for the new controls? Thanks

Comment: I already gave you a link to Xamarin docs where they have full guides on how to do just about everything. Like Universal View (iPhone + iPad) http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello%2C_ipad___universal_apps